# Set a maximum size to the video size ratio

Tags: html, css

Set a maximum size to the video size ratio

```
.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    height: 0;
    max-width: 1024px;
    max-height: 576px;
}

.videoWrapper video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1024px;
    max-height: 576px;
}
```

And HTML code

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
    <video  class="aspect-ratio-box" autoplay>
        <source src="../../../assets/original.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video> 
</div>
```

Here the result : https://prnt.sc/s6y3no

The width size is correctly limited to 1024px. The problem is that the height is not limited. It does not allow to put the paragraph below the video.

Why is he ignoring my css rules? How can I overcome this problem

Thanks for helping

Comment: maybe it's because of the `padding-bottom` of the `.videoWrapper`

Comment: yes, but I need it to do the 16:9 ratio scaling

Comment: @ShidomaruNeveRage you should use 56.25vh in place of 56.25%. I hope that will work.

Comment: @KumarGaurav It no longer extends but the 16:9 ratio is no longer respected. https://prnt.sc/s6yjf3 1024x543 in place of 1024x576

Comment: @ShidomaruNeveRage Try padding-bottom: calc(1024px / 1.77777);

Comment: The problem is that the `padding-bottom: 56.25%;` gives the container a height of 56.25% of the body's width and not the container's width

Comment: @KumarGaurav Now, if i'm trying to make it smaller, the ratio 16:9 is lost https://prnt.sc/s6z3aa

Comment: @SeifEl-DinSweilam Ok, but how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: The only way I managed to solve this was to set the `max-width` of the `body` to `1024px`. This solution isn't the best considering a whole website, but I couldn't find a better one for your purpose till now.

Comment: also consider adding `box-sizing: border-box` to the wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
.video {
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.video-frame {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container {
    max-width: 1024px;
}
```

And HTML

```
<div class="video-container">
    <div class="video-frame">
        <video class="video" autoplay>
            <source src="../../../assets/original.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video> 
    </div>
</div>
```